# KNN and K-means, very different but possible equivalency?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, clustering, k-means, k-nearest-neighbour

Why does the k-nearest neighbor algorithm and k-means clustering algorithm with $k=1$ act the same?

Comment: because k=1 is a degenerate situation. Both methods should be used with k>1 only.

Comment: I don't think KNN with K=1 is degenerate

Answer (score 0):

as @ttnphns stated in his comment, $k = 1$ is meaningless because there is only one cluster per datapoint.

To answer the question in a little more detail, there is a huge theoretical difference in K-means clustering and KNN. KNN requires an implicit construction of an $N \times N$ matrix which can be viewed as a graph with each node being connected to its 5 nearest neighbors.

K-means clustering actually separates the data into clusters which are not connected by edges, but are just classified as belonging to cluster $k$